# How to use allocators in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, c++17, allocator

From what I read in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator , most features of the allocators are now going to be deprecated. The question is, how is one supposed to use allocators in new code? What is the "right" way now?

From what I deduce in the documentation, `construct` is part of the allocator traits, rather than the allocator itself.

I am building a custom container, here it is a very simple version of the constructor, is this a good usage of the new design?

```
container::container(std::size_t size, T const& value, Allocator const& allocator) : allocator_(allocator){
    data_ = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::allocate(allocator_, size);
    for(auto ptr = data_; ptr != data_ + size; ++ptr){
        std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator_, ptr, value)
    }
}
```

I tried to use an algorithm (like `std::for_each`) in the loop but I didn't manage to use one without taking addresses (`operator&`).

Where can I find a complete example of a modern allocator?

---

After some tweaking, I found a way to use an algorithm instead of the the raw loop (to which an execution policy can be passed). I am not very sure, but it could be this:

```
    data_ = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator_, size);
    std::for_each([policy? deduced from allocator?,] 
        boost::make_counting_iterator(data_),
        boost::make_counting_iterator(data_ + size), 
        [&](auto ptr){std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator_, ptr, value);}
    );
```

Comment: This has been the right way to do it since C++11 (modulo the broken `for` loop condition). C++17 changes nothing other than deprecating a bunch of functions that you shouldn't be calling anyway. Also, there's no `construct_n`.

Comment: "*From what I read in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator , most features of the allocators are now going to be stripped out and deprecated.*" Correction: that's not what "deprecated" means. Deprecated does not mean "stripped out". It means "subject to removal in a *later version*". It hasn't gone anywhere yet.

Comment: @T.C., I corrected the code (loop). What would be the right way to write the loop (such that for example one can give an execution policy, `std::for_each`? (of what).

Comment: @NicolBolas, thank you. Yes, I guess I mean what is the new correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the current approach is through `std::allocator_traits`. You'll be able to support the "minimal allocator interface" that way.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator

> Some requirements are optional: the template `std::allocator_traits` supplies the default implementations for all optional requirements, and all standard library containers and other allocator-aware classes access the allocator through `std::allocator_traits`, not directly.

If you observe the `std::allocator_traits` member functions and typedefs, you'll see they're detecting the presence of appropriate function/types and dispatching through them if they can.

The deprecation and potential future removal will change nothing if you're already using `std::allocator_traits` since it only applies to `std::allocator` and their member functions/typedefs.

Now, if you ask me, there's nothing wrong with for-loops, and using `std::for_each` gains you nothing. There are several `uninitialized_*` functions, but they use placement new directly. If you really care you can extract this code to a separate `construct_range` function.

There's also an exception safety issue - in case one of the constructors throws, you need to destroy the earlier elements in order to satisfy the strong exception guarantee and free the memory too (destructor won't get called in case constructor throws)

Comment: I was looking to replace the raw loop, so one can pass execution policies in the future. How would you replace the raw loop by `unitialiazed_*` (which one?)

Comment: @alfC As mentioned in the answer, the `uninitialized_*` (here we're pretty much doing what `uninitialized_fill_n` is doing) functions use placement new directly, not `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct`, so they're not dispatching to the custom construct functions. Now, if you plan to use the execution policies, that could be actually a good thing because you can't be sure whether these allocators' member functions are thread-safe or not, and whether they throw exceptions.

Comment: ok, so `unitialized_*` really shouldn't be used here because they know nothing about the allocator. This forces me to use `std::for_each` but it is confusing to me, because I would do `std::for_each( [policy,] data_, data_ + size, [&](auto&& e){ std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct( allocator_, &e, value) } )` which sounds fishy.

Comment: What you say about execution policy is very interesting because it means that the execution policy should depend on the allocator and effectively it is a trait. At the end, I think it is the `allocator_trait` that should supply a `construct_n` function.